# Mavic Cosmic SLS - carbon separation

Tags: wheels, rims, carbon, aluminum

Some aero’ wheels are an aluminium rim with a carbon fibre shroud. On a Mavic Cosmic SLS rear wheel, I’ve found that the carbon fibre shroud is separating from the aluminium rim. Just visible in the photo, it is delaminating in the same place on both sides over a length of about 10cm:
 [image]

Other side with a pick to show the separation: 
[image]

It’s something I’ve seen before, so to me it’s a known issue- but I don’t know what the solution is. It makes a 1/Rev creaking noise which is a nuisance and I don’t know how quickly it will deteriorate.

At the moment it doesn’t show any damage, it is just separating from the rim. Is it rideable? Is it fixable? Or is the wheel finished?

Comment: From the wear pattern on the rim, it looks to me like the brakes are adjusted too far down.

Comment: @Daniel yes the left pad was slightly too far down, but it hasn’t worn a lip to contact the carbon yet. And the right hand side pad was adjusted fine and rhs is also delaminating. Added mystery! I’m not so concerned with the why it happened, but with knowing what to do about it.

Comment: I see what appears to be a wear mark, just above and to the right of the label.

Comment: What sort of noise are you hearing?

Comment: The carbon part has in fact no load bearing function The SLS is a standard aluminium rim with a glued on light carbon fairing for aerodynamic purposes.

Comment: As @Carel says, the carbon section isn't providing any strength to the wheel.  You could probably either A) glue it back on, or B) cut it off and what you have left is probably a ksyrium

Comment: @AndyP : I'd carefully glue it back with superglue. And rub the brake track with very fine sanding paper to remove any trace of glue.

Comment: I found a web page of somebody’s experiments with rim temperature and they measured peak values up to 150 degrees C on mountain descents, that’s worth bearing in mind for glue choices

Comment: I think a better bet for gluing is epoxy rather than superglue. The plastic component of the carbon will be some kind of epoxy. Although that's a whole world on it's own, so getting one matching the original will be virtually impossible.

Comment: @Swifty, Did you ever find a fix for this issue as I have the same on
my Mavic wheel?

Comment: @Brendan nothing to report, sorry. I don't imagine it's structural, but the space/gap is so tight that in practise it would be a delicate operation to glue or bond. Knowing the noise wasn't structural was comforting. Would love to see if you have any experiments to report!